# MQMapKit (MapQuest) IOS 6 crashing

Tags: ios, mapkit, mapquest

I had a working MKMapKit working in an app Im working on and decided to
convert it to MapQuest's MQMapKit which is supposed to be a drop-in replacement from
what I understand.  After doing so (and checking for any 'MK' map stuff...which I dont
believe I have any now, they are all 'MQ' map references), Im getting the following
crash when the app tries to start up.  Im not sure where 'prepareKeyForNewAnimation'
comes from.  It seems to me to be a MapQuest Library issue (which is version 1.0.1).
Any ideas what is causing this or how to fix it?  Thanks for any help on this!

```
013-05-28 07:01:23.394 myapp[25100:14003] === set USER center
2013-05-28 07:01:23.394 myapp[25100:14003] spanVal <0.300000>
2013-05-28 07:01:23.503 myapp[25100:14003] -[CALayer prepareKeyForNewAnimation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x85781e0
2013-05-28 07:01:23.504 myapp[25100:14003] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer prepareKeyForNewAnimation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x85781e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ec7012 0x1c3ae7e 0x1f524bd 0x1eb6bbc 0x1eb694e 0x55e9b 0x248053f 0x2492014 0x24827d5 0x1e6daf5 0x1e6cf44 0x1e6ce1b 0x2efe7e3 0x2efe668 0xb7effc 0x2042 0x1f75)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception


backtrace:
* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x9bca39c6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x9bca39c6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x90065f78 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_kill + 106
    frame #2: 0x0250157b libsystem_sim_c.dylib`abort + 140
    frame #3: 0x02413f7b libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 105
    frame #4: 0x02411a25 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate() + 34
    frame #5: 0x01c3b0c1 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 94
    frame #6: 0x02393652 libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib`std::terminate() + 21
    frame #7: 0x01c3b039 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_terminate + 11
    frame #8: 0x02492027 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 33
    frame #9: 0x024827d5 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 296
    frame #10: 0x01e6daf5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1925
    frame #11: 0x01e6cf44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #12: 0x01e6ce1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #13: 0x02efe7e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
    frame #14: 0x02efe668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #15: 0x00b7effc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
    frame #16: 0x00002042 myapp`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff364) + 130 at main.m:16
    frame #17: 0x00001f75 myapp`start + 53
```

[EDIT] Very bizarre.  This was happening in the simulator on ipad.  I tried plugging
in my iphone 5 and I got a provisioning error (even though it worked earlier and shouldnt
have been an issue.  When I edited the dev profile and added a couple other users that
I had and re-downloaded it, it still didnt work.  When I went into the settings and changed
the debug/release/distro settings to the generic 'Developer profile' for all three it
now worked fine without crashing.  Bizarre!

[EDIT] NOT so solved....still crashing on and off, mostly on.  Any help would be
appreciated.

[SOLVED] Found this article where I missed adding -ObjC to 'Other Linker Flags':
[mapquest developer site](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/358532)

Comment: Tim, you should either delete your question or enter it as an answer and accept it. :)

Comment: I thought it was solved, but it was not.  Seems to be a sporadic issue, so I removed the 'Solved' from the title.

Comment: Please do not add `solved` to the title of the question. If you solved it, you can post an answer and accept it.